# What plugin is setting my canonical link in wordpress and how do I modify it?

Tags: wordpress

So I am working with a WordPress built site. It is the mobile version of the site. I am very new to this CMS nor did I create the site. The site has a canonical link like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.somewebsite.com/mobile/" />
```

I left the real main URL out of the href attribute. But the URL link is **self referential**. It points to the current page. I have no idea why. But I want it to refer to the Desktop version of the site. Each page has a similar url except minus /mobile. So an about page for the desktop would be:

```
https://www.somewebsite.com/about/
```

Vs mobile

```
https://www.somewebsite.com/mobile/about
```

Edit/Update:

I deactivated all the plugins I could. The following plugins are installed and active:

- Redux Framework
- Webbu Aura Mobile Theme Core Elements

For some reason I could not get them to deactivate. So I a assume it was either one of these two plugins or the wordpress default.

I would appreciate any efforts to help me figure out what is doing this. I was considering using Yaost but I am wondering if that will leave me with TWO canonical links. Which would be bad.

Comment: Disable all plugins at once, refresh the site and look at the canonical tag. If it is still there, it's your theme. If not, reenable all the plugins, step-by-step to check which one is the culprit.

Comment: Will disabling the plugins crash the site or is it safe?

Comment: It's safe to disable all plugins.

Comment: I haven't been able to disable two of the plugins and the link remains. They are up there^

Comment: Do the same with both those plugins (you can safely re-active them afterwards). It would be *very* helpful to know which to debug - the theme itself or the plugins.